# Grails: Transients property in Constraints.groovy

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I want to replace domain class in grails with a hibernate class(Rate). So constrains to hibernate class can be added by creating a file `RateConstraints.groovy` in src/java, and it works fine for validations of hibernate class.  now i need to add transients property to hibernate class using this `RateConstraints.groovy`.

Eg:

Consider a java Class

```
class Rate {        
        Long id 
        String code         
    }
```

`RateConstraints.groovy` file in ../src/java

```
constraints = { 
    id ( nullable:true )
    code( nullable: false )
}
```

How can i add transients  property in `RateConstraints.groovy` file

```
transients = ['startDate', 'endDate']
```

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer

`RateConstraints.groovy` file in ../src/java

transients = ['startDate', 'endDate']

```
Rate.metaClass.getStartDate << {-> startDate  }
Rate.metaClass.setStartDate << {it -> startDate = it }
Rate.metaClass.getEndDate << {-> endDate  }
Rate.metaClass.setEndDate << {it -> endDate = it }

constraints = { 
    id ( nullable:true )
    code( nullable: false )
}
```

it works

Comment: That makes no sense.  Where are you putting that code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. If you want to mark a property in a hibernate POJO as transient then you use the regular `@Transient` annotation in the POJO itself (or just don't map it at all if you're using hbm.xml).